# Почему не очищается память при запросах к БД?

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть участок кода, приведенный ниже, который загружает картинку на сервер, сохраняет её в БД wordpress + thumbnail.

```
function generateFeaturedImage( $image_url, $post_id, $i  ){

    $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
    $filename = basename($image_url).$i;
    if(wp_mkdir_p($upload_dir['path'])) {
        $file = $upload_dir['path'] . '/' . $filename;
    } else {
        $file = $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/' . $filename;
    }
    file_put_contents($file, file_get_contents($image_url));

    $wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype($filename, null );
    $attachment = array(
        'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
        'post_title' => sanitize_file_name($filename),
        'post_content' => '',
        'post_status' => 'inherit'
    );
    $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $file, $post_id );
    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');
    $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $file );
    wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );
    set_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $attach_id );

}
```

Вот такой замер потребления памяти

```
for($i=0; $i<10; $i++) {
    $START2 = microtime(true);
    generateFeaturedImage('img.jpg', 1778, $i);
    echo 'memory for create img: ' . (memory_get_usage() - $s) . "\n";
    echo "$i time: " . (microtime(true) - $START2) . " sec" . PHP_EOL;
}
```

показывает следующие результаты

```
0 time: 0.33364510536194 sec
memory for create img: 156480
1 time: 0.23405408859253 sec
memory for create img: 160816
2 time: 0.23686289787292 sec
memory for create img: 165152
3 time: 0.25216603279114 sec
memory for create img: 169488
4 time: 0.2624979019165 sec
memory for create img: 173824
5 time: 0.29374694824219 sec
memory for create img: 178160
6 time: 0.25813889503479 sec
memory for create img: 182816
7 time: 0.27913498878479 sec
memory for create img: 187152
8 time: 0.32186794281006 sec
memory for create img: 191808
9 time: 0.29191112518311 sec
memory for create img: 196144
Total time: 2.76442694664 sec
```

То есть, с каждой итерацией, расход памяти увеличивается на ~5000 bytes
Если увеличить цикл до 10000 итераций, то расход будет составлять ~50мегабайт. `unset()` всех переменных в этом куске не помогает. `gc_collect_cycles()` естественно тоже.

Вопрос: в каком месте накапливается память и почему она не очищается? Если написать запросы собственноручно, удастся ли избежать этого эффекта?

Comment: unset($_POST) пробовали?

Comment: Нет. картинка не из `$_POST` приходит. Консольный скрипт

Comment: А die() или wp_die() в конце функции пробовали?

Comment: А зачем? скрипт ведь тогда завершится.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что в WordPress кешируется всё или почти всё. Созданные вами посты типа attachment остаются в кеше, который надо чистить функциями

```
wp_cache_delete( $post->ID, 'posts' );
wp_cache_delete( $post->ID, 'post_meta' );
```

Это те функции, которые удалось увидеть при поверхностном просморте кода ядра, отвечающего за добавление вложений (картинок).

Comment: Конкретно в данном цикле, применить не получится? Точнее, я добавил эти строчки, эффекта нет.

Comment: Зато `wp_cache_flush()`, кажется, помог!

Comment: 1. Вы, конечно, понимаете, что вместо $post->ID должен быть $attach_id,  ну и т.д.? 2. Возможно, ещё что-то кешируется, посмотрите код вызываемых вами функций.

Comment: На вопрос "почему" я ответил, а вот какие именно кеши чистить и как - это уже вы ищите сами. Прикладное значение "как" близко к нулю, потому что никто в одном цикле не грузит 10 тыс картинок на сервер.

Comment: Спасибо. Вообще, весь скрипт консольный. Задача - закачать из стороннего АПИ всю базу товаров. В этом случае, кэш никакой роли не играет и от него можно избавляться, чтобы не захламлял, я думаю?

Comment: Это можно, конечно